# Simple calculator in xmonad prompt

Tags: haskell, xmonad

i have a new idea of using xmonad's XMonad.Prompt.Input. I thought it would be really cool, if one could make a simple calculator that would compute what the user enters and return the result in the next prompt's text, finishing when the user presses escape...  The problem is, that I don't quite know how to deal with the types...

So far I have this:

```
runAndGetOutput cmd = do
    (_, pout, _, phandle) <- runInteractiveCommand cmd
    waitForProcess phandle
    a <- hGetContents pout
    return a 

calcPrompt :: XPConfig -> String -> X () 
calcPrompt c ans =
    inputPrompt c ans ?+ \ next -> 
        calcPrompt c (runAndGetOutput ("calc" ++  next))
```

Which doesn't work. I get:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[Char]' with actual type `IO String'
Expected type: String
Actual type: IO String
In the return type of a call of `runAndGetOutput'
In the second argument of `calcPrompt', namely
`(runAndGetOutput ("calc" ++ next))'
```

I do understand it has something to do with the fact that runAndGetOutput returns IO String and I need a normal String for inputPrompt included from import XMonad.Prompt.Input. But I have no clue how to deal with that...

Thanks a lot for your help!

**EDIT:**
Now I have this:

```
runAndGetOutput :: String -> IO String
runAndGetOutput cmd = do
    (_, pout, _, phandle) <- runInteractiveCommand cmd
    a <- hGetContents pout
        waitForProcess phandle
        return a 

calcPrompt :: XPConfig -> String -> X () 
calcPrompt c ans =
    inputPrompt c ans ?+ \next ->
        liftIO (runAndGetOutput ("echo -n " ++ next)) >>= calcPrompt c
```

Which compiles, but doesn't work as expected. I can open the prompt, enter some text, then it launches the shell command, but then it just discards the stdo value instead of using it as a new prompt text.

I would expect the version with echo do following: When I open the prompt, some default string is shown. When I enter a value and press return, another prompt opens with the value previously entered (thanks to echo which just returns what it has got). If it worked with echo, i would replace echo with some bash script to perform the calculations and return the result instead of echo.

**Recent EDIT:**
Finally resolved. The final code of my small calc snippet is in my self-answer:) Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the functions available in [XMonad.Util.Run](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Util-Run.html), which take care of a few xmonad-specific details (some signal-handling, I think).

Answer (score 1):

`X` has a `MonadIO` instance, so

```
calcPrompt c ans =
    inputPrompt c ans ?+ \next ->
        liftIO (runAndGetOutput ("calc" ++ next)) >>= calcPrompt c
```

should work, I think.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It compiles fine now. However, it doesn't work as expected. I replaced "calc" with "echo ", which, according to my idea should push the value from user back to another calcPromt, and the new calcPrompt should show the last entered value in the previous one. However, the next prompt is never displayed. The command in runAndGetOutput is performed (I tried with "touch") though...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys... You are great :) Now it works. My final code is so short:

```
...
import XMonad.Prompt
import XMonad.Prompt.Input
import Data.Char (isSpace)

...    

calcPrompt :: XPConfig -> String -> X () 
calcPrompt c ans =
    inputPrompt c (trim ans) ?+ \input -> 
        liftIO(runProcessWithInput "qalc" [input] "") >>= calcPrompt c 
    where
        trim  = f . f
            where f = reverse . dropWhile isSpace
```

Just for the others: to use this tiny calc integrated in xmonad, I call it by a key binding like this one:

```
, ((modm, xK_KP_Multiply), calcPrompt defaultXPConfig "qalc" )
```

Of course you need qalc installed. I think this is rather handy snippet, because it's not just a calc, you can basically call any executable that produces some short output: calculator, dictionary, whatever you like...